# Finding the derivative of an integral with variable limits: ${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}\int_{x}^{x^2}{1 \over -2y}e^{-5xy^{2}}\mathrm{d}y$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

How do you compute the derivative

$${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}\int_{x}^{x^2}{1 \over -2y}e^{-5xy^{2}}\mathrm{d}y$$

where the integral has variable limits?

Comment: See the Leibniz Integral Rule [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement).

Comment: @Mattos Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}\int_{a}^{b^2}{1 \over -2y}e^{-5xy^{2}}\mathrm{d}y=\dfrac1{4x}(e^{-5xa^{2}}-e^{-5xb^{4}})$$
$${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}a}\int_{a}^{b^2}{1 \over -2y}e^{-5xy^{2}}\mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{2a}e^{-5xa^2}$$
$${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}b}\int_{a}^{b^2}{1 \over -2y}e^{-5xy^{2}}\mathrm{d}y=-\frac{1}{b}e^{-5xb^4}$$
With $a=b=x$
$${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}\int_{x}^{x^2}{1 \over -2y}e^{-5xy^{2}}\mathrm{d}y=\dfrac1{4x}(e^{-5x^{3}}-e^{-5x^{5}})+\frac{1}{2x}e^{-5x^3}-\frac{1}{x}e^{-5x^5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is a function of two variables. Define the function $F$ by

$$F(u, v, x) = \int_{u}^{v} f(x, y) \, dy$$

where $u = u(x)$ and $v = v(x)$. Then using the multivariable chain rule to $F$ differentiate with respect to $x$ yields

$$
\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}.
$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} = -f(x, u) \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} = f(x, v).
$$

We therefore have

$$
\frac{dF}{dx} = -f(x, u) \frac{du}{dx} + f(x, v) \frac{dv}{dx} + \int_{u}^{v} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigl( f(x, y) \bigr) \, dy, \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

where for the final term we have differentiated under the integral sign.

---

In your case we want to find $\dfrac{dF}{dx}$ where

- $f(x, y) = -\dfrac{1}{2y}\mathrm{e}^{-5xy^2}$,
- $u(x) = x$,
- $v(x) = x^2$.

Computing using the formula $(\dagger)$ above gives the required result,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dF}{dx}
&= -f(x, x) + 2x \ f(x, x^2) + \int_{x}^{x^2} \frac{5}{2}y \mathrm{e}^{-5xy^2} \, dy\\
&= \frac{1}{2x}\mathrm{e}^{-5x^3} + \frac{2x}{2x^2}\mathrm{e}^{-5x^5} + \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-5xy^2}}{-2x} \right]_{y=x}^{y=x^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2x}\mathrm{e}^{-5x^3} + \frac{1}{2x}\mathrm{e}^{-5x^5} - \frac{1}{4x}\left( \mathrm{e}^{-5x^5} - \mathrm{e}^{-5x^3} \right).
\end{align*}$$